# Which one is better DOTSUB or AMARA

Tags: video, caption, subtitle, closed-captions, webvtt

I am looking for a user friendly caption creator which support multiple language. I have come across [AMARA](http://www.amara.org/) and [DOTSUB](http://dotsub.com/).Both are looking pretty good, hard to choose , so i was looking for some expert opinion.

> I will be using Jwplayer for my videos (if this factor also affect the
>   caption creation, I would like to know). Also I have all the videos in
>   CDN cloudfront, videos are of mp4 format.

So far i have come across
[how_is_your_experiences_with_amara](http://www.ted.com/conversations/11227/how_is_your_experiences_with.html) and [video-subtitling-captioning-and-translation-tools-amara-versus-dotsub](http://www.worddelights.com/blog/gnome-outreach-program-for-women/video-subtitling-captioning-and-translation-tools-amara-versus-dotsub), both are not giving me correct answer, help me choose the best one.